# Problems with KeePass2 Plugins

Tags: plugins, compatibility, keepass

KeePass is an integral part of any PC build I own, and recently I've tinkered with trying to get it to work on Ubuntu. After a lot of attempts I finally got Global Auto-Type to function, but there are still some problems with plugins that I use regularly on Windows. There are 4 plugins that don't work on Ubuntu: CheckPasswordBox, KPEnhancedEntryView, CustomIconDashboard, and ExelconPicker. The only one I absolutely require for my KeePass setup to work is CheckPasswordBox though, and most of the others I don't use often and could live without. Also, I'm trying to use Wine as a middleman to fix this problem, so if that ends up working then IDK I guess my problems are now fixed. Do try to help though.

Comment: There's a great deal of work going on with Firefox Native Messaging, which KeePass uses, and which was broken by the transition from Deb to Snap in 22.04: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-native-messaging-support-in-the-firefox-snap/29759. It's unclear if your work is related; the question [could be improved](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423563/edit) by including your release of Ubuntu, the browsers you are using, and the sources/package-methods you are using to install those browsers.

Comment: Personally I find KeepassXC better than Keepass2. Of course this won't solve the Snap-Firefox problem in Ubuntu 22.04. That problem will be solved with the release of [Firefox version 104](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/07/ubuntu-devs-fix-another-frustrating-firefox-snap-flaw) later this month.